# How to scrape a list of films from Letterboxd with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I wanted to scrape and print the names of the films included on the page
https://letterboxd.com/films/decade/1980s/ using `BeautifulSoup` and `Requests`.

I have to admit that I am quite new to web scraping, so I am having a hard time figuring out where the problem might be and why the `list` of movie titles is empty (After running it in PYCharm, it says `[]` and "Process finished with exit code 0")

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://letterboxd.com/films/decade/1980s/"
response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    film_elements = soup.find_all("li", class_="listitem poster-container")
    film_titles = [element.find("span", class_="frame-title").text for element in film_elements]
    print(film_titles)
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve the webpage.")
```

As you can see I tried to send a get-request to the URL and check whether it was succesful. If yes, it creates a `BeautifulSoup` object from the HTML content and finds all elements with the "listitem poster-container" class. Then it extracts the text from the elements with the "frame-title" class and stores it in the `film_titles` list. At the end, I want to print it.

Comment: Data to the page is fetched via javascript - if you check the request response, you will see there's a div that has dataurl attribute.

Comment: So using selenium could be the right approach?

Comment: selenium, playwright or call the dataurl directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, content is loaded via separat source, check browsers dev tools network section for xhr tab. Some of the data could be fetched from there, for further details, not displayed on website, you have to iterate each `movie_url`, but this is not focus of question.

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(
            requests.get('https://letterboxd.com/films/ajax/popular/decade/1980s/?esiAllowFilters=true').text
)

for e in soup.select('li.listitem'):
    data.append({
        'title':e.img.get('alt'),
        'img_url':e.img.get('src'),
        'rating':e.get('data-average-rating'),
        'movie_url':'https://letterboxd.com'+e.div.get('data-film-slug')
})
data
```

##### Output

```
[{'title': 'The Shining',
  'img_url': 'https://s.ltrbxd.com/static/img/empty-poster-70.8112b435.png',
  'rating': '4.26',
  'movie_url': 'https://letterboxd.com/film/the-shining/'},
 {'title': 'Back to the Future',
  'img_url': 'https://s.ltrbxd.com/static/img/empty-poster-70.8112b435.png',
  'rating': '4.19',
  'movie_url': 'https://letterboxd.com/film/back-to-the-future/'},
 {'title': 'Dead Poets Society',
  'img_url': 'https://s.ltrbxd.com/static/img/empty-poster-70.8112b435.png',
  'rating': '4.23',
  'movie_url': 'https://letterboxd.com/film/dead-poets-society/'},
 {'title': 'The Empire Strikes Back',
  'img_url': 'https://s.ltrbxd.com/static/img/empty-poster-70.8112b435.png',
  'rating': '4.39',
  'movie_url': 'https://letterboxd.com/film/the-empire-strikes-back/'},...]
```

Comment: But to achieve this, you would have to work with Selenium as well, since the information on the respective pages of the films is fetched with JavaScript, right? Then you would also need a fake user agent etc.

Comment: If this is a question, then this would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus, cause it is not addressed in your OP.  On the other hand if it is a determination, then I would say why not work with requests here too, it depends on the information that is needed and whether you are willing to trade ease for unnecessary overhead. my advice, whenever you can, keep it simple.

Comment: That was meant more as a yes/no question. I am currently trying to read out the number of watchers of each film. To do this, I'm trying to access each URL and read out, for example, the 316K from here "<a href="/film/eraserhead/members/" class="has-icon icon-watched icon-16 tooltip" data-original-title="Watched by 316,343&nbsp;members"><span class="icon"></span>316K</a>" (That seems easier to me than getting the "316,343"). I just feel like I'm doing it a lot more awkwardly than I thought, since I'm using Selenium and fake-useragent.

Comment: In that case I would answer quite clearly. No, `selenium` is not needed for that. The corresponding endpoint (https://letterboxd.com/esi/film/eraserhead/stats/) provides modularly exactly the part that is needed.  As for your example, it is neither a question of `requests` nor `selenium` or similar, it is simply practice and preference -> `int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, soup.a.get('title'))))` will give you a nice `int` to work with ro use some regex if you prefer.